# Django custom admin template has_change_permission is always None

Tags: django, admin

I have a custom admin template where I need to check `has_add_permission` and `has_change_permission` values. I can see that the `has_add_permission` has `True/False` according to the permission assigned to the user. The value of `has_change_permission` is always `None`. For instance:

```
{% if has_add_permission %}
    {# The condition has a True/False value #}
    ...
{% endif %}

{% if has_change_permission %}
    {# Never executed because the condition is always None #}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

How can I determine if the user can change a table?

Comment: Can you share your admin.py code where you plugged this custom template

Comment: I'm overriding the `change_form.html` template for some of the models.

Answer (score 0):

If *what* has the permission?  Try something like:

```
{% if user.has_add_permission %}
    {# The condition has a True/False value #}
    ...
{% endif %}
```